# How to read complete data from the device?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, gps

Can any one explain How to read complete data from the device.. Here the problem is GPS is sending huge stored data at a time but the TCP socket will handle the data . But its not able to read complete data where the device sending .. please help me how to handle this one.

Thanks.

Comment: "The device"? Which one is that, exactly? Read what? You need to be more specific and provide more information.

Comment: The device is visiontek(Client) . The GPS will sending raw_packet in every minute to Visiontek device  . I have to read complete data what ever the device is sending to Server.

Answer (score 0):

Well...  I suggest that you start by looking over your complete set of requirements and that you look for any existing interface-libraries that may have been built to handle either *this* device or (more likely...) a *generic set* of similar devices.

*"Actum Ne Agas:  Do Not Do A Thing Already Done."*

When a device starts sending data, it's necessarily going to be sending it to you in chunks according to *some* well-known protocol ... and it is utterly and completely pointless to try to write *your own* code to handle that, given that you're certainly not the first programmer out there who's had to do that selfsame thing.